# Javascript try/catch scope

Tags: javascript, scope, try-catch

I'm writing a code which is making Ajax request to a server. I'm using try/catch for error handling, outside the request, as you can see below. The search method is sending the request to the server, and if it can read the results, it calls the callback function.

I'm asking this: since ajax requests are asynchronous, if there is an error inside the callback(not inside the search method), would it fall into the outer catch block or do I need another try/catch in the callback function?

```
try {
    service.search(function () {
        var entries = service.getEntries();
        $.each(entries, function (index, content) {
            var cat = {
                // those may throw exceptions, too
                name: content.get("category"),
                path: content.getPath()
            };
            categories.push(cat); // defined somewhere else.
        });
        if (categories.length < totalResults) {
            // A method call may throw exception
        } else if (typeof loadCallback === 'function') {
            // Done.
        }
    });
} catch (e) {

}
```

Comment: I m not sure but I guess `service.search()` would have an `onerror` callback parameter which could be used to catch exceptions, But as far as your question concern I guess it'll be caught by that catch block, But not sure of course.

Comment: I guess the answer could be 'it depends'... as @yogi said, the asynchronous method should have some callback parameter to check for errors after completion.

Comment: It requires too much code to use callbacks in my case, since I have too much functions calling each other like a chain. Then I need to write callbacks to each of them.

Comment: Async callbacks run in a different call stack (by the time they run the original call stack that created them is long lost and forgotten). You can't catch errors thrown there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two or three year of javascript developing, I found that the best way of catching errors on ajax requests is to have multiple callbacks: one for success and one for error.

I've changed all of the methods in Netmera HTML5 SDK and now we don't need any try/catch block. All we need to do is to pass two function arguments:

```
service.search(function(dataArray) {
    // loop through dataArray
}, function(exception) {
    // Exception detail
}
```

And inside the search method, its something like:

```
this.search = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    ...
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                successCallback(...);
            } else {
                errorCallback(...);
            }
        }
    };
    request.ontimeout = function () {
        errorCallback(...);
    };

    request.send(...);
};
```